# Error al ejecutar el boot de FROG No se puede cargar el archivo DLL 'SQLite.Iterop.dll'

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

Al ejecutar el instalable de FROG Ventas y Distribución tengo el siguiente error en algunas maquinas Windows : No se puede cargar el archivo DLL 'SQLite.Iterop.dll': No se puede encontrar el módulo especifico

He revisado y no sé a que se deba.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: simplemente esa librería no esta en tu equipo, busca como instalarla manualmente, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que descargar los componente para aplicaciones desarrolladas en C
acá te dejo el nombre del ejecutable:

-Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)

https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=26999https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=26999

Saludos!..